# Can EntityManager be used only within transaction?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, entitymanager

This must be obvious thing as it is not mentioned anywhere but I still feel need to have it confirmed.

Does `EntityManager` always need to be in transaction if it is to be used in persist operations?

The following application-managed `EntityManager` code does not persist anything unless I enclose it in `getTransaction().begin()` and  `getTransaction().commit()`:

```
   EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();

    Event e  = new Event("A name", new Date());
    em.persist(e);
```

But the `find()` invocation works ok.

1. Does this mean that I cannot used EM for write/update operations unless within a  transaction? If so why no exception was thrown when I tried to used it without transaction? Can EM be set to create automatically begin and commit the transaction if it is not within a transaction?
2. In case of container managed EM is still a reference to the same EM instance injected within one transaction to various components involved in transaction or can multiple EM instances share 1 transaction?
3. Can 1 EM instance be used in multiple transactions ?

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that I cannot used EM for write/update operations
>   unless within a transaction?

Yes this is correct any write or update to the database must be within a transaction

> If so why no exception was thrown when I tried to used it without
>   transaction?

Find Method is not required to be within a transaction as it does not affect data. You can run your query outside of the transaction. Since fetch (or find) is immutable, the query will succeed

> Can EM be set to create automatically begin and commit the
>   transaction if it is not within a transaction?

This involve some concepts of Container Managed Transactions, that create the begin , commit and end of the transactions by its owns, but as you are using Bean Managed Transaction you must create start and commit transactions by your own.

> In case of container managed EM is still a reference to the same EM
>   instance injected within one transaction to various components
>   involved in transaction or can multiple EM instances share 1
>   transaction?

In the case of container managed EM, the EM is obtained through dependency injection (`@PersistenceContext`) or JNDI, the container manages the persistent context life cycle and always use JTA, which is means that the persistence context is propagated with the current JTA transaction, so using multiples EM instances in different beans could share the same transaction if TransactionalAttributes allow `(REQUIRED, MANDATORY, SUPPORTS)`. So answer to your question multiples EM can share the same transaction.

> Can 1 EM instance be used in multiple transactions ?

No, EM is associate with one transaction, it does allow use multiple transactions simultaneously.
A Persistence Context can be associated with either single or multiple transactions and can be associated with multiple Entity Managers but EM does not support be involved in multiple transaction. But it can be used in different transaction but not at the same moment.

Comment: I like your answer and also the way to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some JPA implementations support nontransactional writes. Some don't. For implementation-independent behaviour you use transactions. If your JPA provider allows nontransactional operations then you can find writing code much easier